# IList List is null in my Composition Class .. WHY?

Tags: list, c#-4.0, composition, ilist

I am usling IList List property to get a list of students class in University class .. as i try to access this list in department Class which is a part of university class .. the List is Null .. can anyone tell the reason?

```
namespace UniversitySystem
{
  class University : CollectionBase
  {
    private string _uniName;
    Departments _depart = new Departments();


    public University(string un, string dn, string cp, List<Student> Slist)
    {
        this._uniName = un;
        this.CED.DepartName = dn;
        this.CED.ChairPerson = cp;
        foreach (Student s in Slist)
        {
            List.Add(s);
        }
    }

    #region properties

    public string UniName
    {
        get { return _uniName; }
        set { _uniName = value; }
    }

    public Departments CED
    {
        get { return _depart; }
        set { _depart = value; }
    }

    #endregion


    public class Departments : CollectionBase
    {
        private string _departName;

        public string DepartName
        {
            get { return _departName; }
            set { _departName = value; }
        }
        private string _chairPerson;

        public string ChairPerson
        {
            get { return _chairPerson; }
            set { _chairPerson = value; }
        }
        public List<Student> StudentListForCED = new List<Student>();


        public Departments()
        {
            _departName = null;
            _chairPerson = null;
            StudentListForCED = null;
        }

        public Departments(string dn, string cp, List<Student> Slist)
        {
            this._departName = dn;
            this._chairPerson = cp;
            foreach (Student s in Slist)
            {
                List.Add(s);
            }
        }

        public void showDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Departmental Info");
            Console.WriteLine("DepartmentName: " + _departName);
            Console.WriteLine("Chairperson Name: " + _chairPerson);
            Console.WriteLine("Student Info:");
            foreach (Student item in List)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("deptName: " + item.RegNo);
                Console.WriteLine("total marks:  " + item.TotalMarksObtained);
                Console.WriteLine("percentage:   " + item.GetPercentage());
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**THE main() part is**

```
namespace UniversitySystem
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Student> slist = new List<Student>();
        slist.Add(new Student("sana", 1234, "CIS", 650));
        slist.Add(new Student("anam", 2345, "BCIT", 400));
        slist.Add(new Student("fizzza", 2670, "Electrical", 670));


        University u1 = new University("NED", "computer", "UKP", slist);
        Console.WriteLine(u1.CED.DepartName);
        u1.CED.showDetails();



    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where/how is `List` declared and initialized?

Comment: Its in the Collection Base class.. A property already declared as IList List .. i m just using that property

Comment: You can't name a variable List.

Comment: Sir, its not a variable its one of the property in .NET class named as CollectionBase .. u can check out urself!

Comment: it returns the items in the current list as a IList. and we can use all the methods on this property which are declared in IList class .. hence i have used this

Comment: The way you are trying to use List is like that of a variable.  It is incorrect.  Hence, it is not working.  And. I am not a sir.

Comment: Oops .. extremely sorry .. I usually call 'Sir' as to give respect to others

Answer (score 1):

The initializing code for University does not store the list you give it as a parameter.

try storing the list in a variable in either the department or the university object itself, and when you are showing the details for either of those object you can reference that list, the one you stored upon creating the object.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Since you are writing your code in an object oriented fashion, you should let the objects take care of the states and values associated with themselves.

Comment: LOgard: i tried that but an error says that **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
when i pass the list of ann no. of objects to University Constructor

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple changes that should work.

```
    public Departments(string dn, string cp, List<Student> Slist)
    {
        this._departName = dn;
        this._chairPerson = cp;
        foreach (Student s in Slist)
        {
            StudentListForCED.Add(s);
        }
    }

    public void showDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Departmental Info");
        Console.WriteLine("DepartmentName: " + _departName);
        Console.WriteLine("Chairperson Name: " + _chairPerson);
        Console.WriteLine("Student Info:");
        foreach (Student item in StudentListForCED)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("deptName: " + item.RegNo);
            Console.WriteLine("total marks:  " + item.TotalMarksObtained);
            Console.WriteLine("percentage:   " + item.GetPercentage());
        }
    }
```

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx) a little more thoroughly.